# How to include the last element in the for loop? (Run the last element along with all other elements)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have searched around, and have only found answers to questions like, "How to detect the last element?", or, "How to extract/change/skip to the last element?", which are not quite what I need.

I want to run a for loop of a list, from the first element to the last element of the list, instead of to the second last element. I don't want the last element to be any more special than all other elements; I just want it to be included while I run the for loop.

If there is a small piece of code that I can embed in the function, that would be great. I'm also fine with creating a separate function, then call that function when needed (I'm a newbie, so if you are going to do this approach, please also include how I would call another function within my function).

Here's my code (without running the last element):

```
**import sympy
from sympy import Q
k,l,m,n=sympy.symbols('k l m n')
Z=sympy.symbols('Z')
sol_list=[]
def findZ(k,l,m,n,Z):       
    max_loop=len(coeff_list)
    for i in range(max_loop): # <- Here's the trouble-maker
        k=coeff_list[i][0]
        l=coeff_list[i][1]
        m=coeff_list[i][2]
        n=coeff_list[i][3]
        expr=k*Z**3+l*Z**2+m*Z+n
        sol=sympy.solve(expr,'Z')
        for sol in sol:
            if sympy.ask(Q.real(sol))==True:
                sol_list.append(sol)
        if len(sol_list)>1:
            max(sol_list)
    remove_dup(sol_list)
    return sol_list**
```

**coeff_list=[[1, -1.0000007185951756, 0.2959936217035236, -2.1269958855852493e-07], [1, -1.0000006956368632, 0.27738242112279193, -1.9295743735357098e-07], [1, -1.0000006741001182, 0.26047291179805043, -1.755848206487531e-07],[...]**

If it helps, coeff_list is a list within a list, with the length of the coeff_list is 24. Each nested list contains 4 items.

Comment: a `for` loop **DOES** iterate over all the elements of it's iterable. Please edit your question with a __proper__ [mcve] (something that doesn't requires external packages, and only have the _minimal_ code needed to reproduce the issue).

Comment: Also (mostly unrelated but) you don't need this `range(len(coeff_list))` thing - it's Python, not C, you can [directly iterate over your iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: Bruno, you're right: a for loop, when uses with range, does iterate from the first element to the last element - but here's the kicker: once it "meets" the last element, the loop breaks there and does NOT process the last element! So I start with a list with the length of 24, and end with a resulting list whose length is 23. Do you see my point there?

Comment: To your another suggestion, if I put coeff_list instead of range(len(coeff_list)), the program returns a message, "list indices must be integers or slices, not list" for my k=coeff_list[i][0]. I need my k=coeff_list[i][0], because coeff_list is a list of list, so I want to iterate through coeff_list, and assign names to 4 items within each nested list. If you have another way to accomplish this, please let me know.